# ASP.Net Core Identity overwrite default behaviour

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Started learning full-stack programming with all-new languages.
At the back-end I have ASP.Net Core Web API project, at front-end, I have Vue.js SPA

Managed to add pretty much barebones Identity and configure it for my liking. However, it still has some "hard-coded" stuff like redirection query params.

Accessing endpoint with [Authorize] attribute while being unauthorized redirects me to page I set via `LoginPath` option in cookies auth, but it adds pre-defined query param `ReturnUrl` as well as some additional logic. I assume this is part of the `ChallengeAsync` call that happens under the hood.

Is there any way I either can overwrite behavior in my controller or anywhere else?

Comment: So far I'm just overwriting path via cookie events and handle redirects in my app. But that would be good to use existing server-side features.

Comment: You can specify `options.ReturnUrlParameter` to override the query parameter. If you need more control, you can redirect to one of your own controller actions and handle the redirects yourself.

Comment: Scaffold the auth views and see how Identity framework makes things work, then start customizing from there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio